# factory girl - know when an attribute is overridden in factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

Is there any way to determine if attributes are overridden in a factory and adjust the behavior of the factory based on those overrides?

The evaluator passed into the [callbacks](http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Callbacks) contains a __override_names__ method.  Unfortunately, by the time it is passed to the callback, every attribute configured by the factory is included in the array returned.  Moreover, the Evaluator is marked as api private.

Comment: Can you give an example of the use case you're imagining? Factory Girl's [callbacks](http://rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Callbacks) and [lazy attributes](http://rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Lazy_Attributes) (mainly the latter) should cover most uses.

Comment: @colinm -- sorry for the delay.  i didn't realize that anyone had commented on this.

Comment: @colinm I've run into this issue, and I have some logic that should run only if an association was not overridden.

Comment: This is an old question, but I just came across a possible use case and wrote a new one, with an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76509394/factory-bot-is-there-a-way-to-make-an-attribute-value-conditional-based-on-ove

Comment: The question I'd linked above now has an accepted answer.